# How to determine error if IIS 6 is redirecting to a different page based on error?

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, error-handling

Ok, this might seem confusing, but basically, its this:

There's a form on an asp page (not .net), which sends info to a MS SQL 2000 based server, running on IIS6 (I think, it might be IIS 5.1). The server is configured to only accept digits, but the form is not validated.

So when the user keys in alphabets, and submits, an error is displayed. I have configured IIS to redirect to a different page based on the http error code, ("sorry, the page you requested cannot be loaded at this time"), but now I, as a developer, don't know what the error code is all about.

Is there a way I can configure the error page to 'OnLoad' send an email containing the page address that caused the error, the error message itself, time of error, current user that's logged in, etc.? I'm open to any solutions, client side javascript, or server side asp code... Even IIS configs are valid answers now.. Lol...

Answer (score 0):

In IIS, Custom Errors tab > change the 500 error to type URL file 'error.asp'

In the error.asp, you could loop the form, querystring and session elements and also send the error details to home in on the error.

```
    Dim ASPErr ,ASPErrStr,intKey
  Dim strQueryStringElement,strQueryStringValue,strCurrentQueryString
  Dim strFormElement,strFormValue,strCurrentForm  
    Dim strSessElement,strSessValue,strCurrentSess
  Set ASPErr = Server.GetLastError()

  ASPErrStr = ""
  ASPErrStr = ASPErrStr&vbcrlf&"ASPCode: "&ASPErr.ASPCode
  ASPErrStr = ASPErrStr&vbcrlf&"ASPDescription: "&ASPErr.ASPDescription
  ASPErrStr = ASPErrStr&vbcrlf&"Category: "&ASPErr.Category
  ASPErrStr = ASPErrStr&vbcrlf&"Column: "&ASPErr.Column
  ASPErrStr = ASPErrStr&vbcrlf&"Description: "&ASPErr.Description
  ASPErrStr = ASPErrStr&vbcrlf&"File: "&ASPErr.File
  ASPErrStr = ASPErrStr&vbcrlf&"Line: "&ASPErr.Line
  ASPErrStr = ASPErrStr&vbcrlf&"Number: "&ASPErr.Number
  ASPErrStr = ASPErrStr&vbcrlf&"Source: "&ASPErr.Source



For Each intKey in Request.QueryString
    strQueryStringElement = Request.QueryString.Key(intKey)
    strQueryStringValue = Request.QueryString.Item(strQueryStringElement)         
    strCurrentQueryString = strCurrentQueryString & "Element: "& _ 
    strQueryStringElement & ".........Value: " &strQueryStringValue& VBCRLF
Next

For Each intKey in Request.Form
    strFormElement = Request.Form.Key(intKey)
    strFormValue = Request.Form.Item(strFormElement)         
    strCurrentForm =    strCurrentForm & "Element: "& _ 
    strFormElement & ".........Value: " &strFormValue&VBCRLF
Next

For Each intKey in Session.Contents
    strSessElement = intKey
    strSessValue = Session(intKey)
    strCurrentSess =    strCurrentSess & "Element: "& _ 
    strSessElement & ".........Value: " &strSessValue& vbcrlf
Next

ASPErrStr = ASPErrStr&vbcrlf&"QueryString: "
ASPErrStr = ASPErrStr&vbcrlf&strCurrentQueryString
ASPErrStr = ASPErrStr&vbcrlf&"Form: "
ASPErrStr = ASPErrStr&vbcrlf&strCurrentForm
ASPErrStr = ASPErrStr&vbcrlf&"Session: "
ASPErrStr = ASPErrStr&vbcrlf&strCurrentSess

Set myMail=CreateObject("CDO.Message")
myMail.Subject="Error"
myMail.From="someone@address.com"
myMail.To="someoneelse@address.com"
myMail.TextBody= ASPErrStr
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing")=2
'Name or IP of remote SMTP server
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver")="smtpserveraddress"
'Server port
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport")=25 
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Update
myMail.Send
set myMail=nothing
  %>
```